# Reading an unformatted Fortran file with Python scipy.io

Tags: python, while-loop, scipy, valueerror, try-except

At the moment I am working on a Python module that is supposed to read a Fortran file. The first record has a fixed beginning:

```
recl = ['a20', 'i4', 'a20', 'a6', 'a1', 'i4', 'i4', 'a1', 'i4']
```

This is the smallest possible size. However, the `recl` has an unknown length. What is known is that more `('i4', 'i4')` blocks will be added.
So the next possible size is

```
recl = ['a20', 'i4', 'a20', 'a6', 'a1', 'i4', 'i4', 'a1', 'i4', "i4", "i4"]
```

etc. My idea is the following :

```
def read_ff(fname):
    from scipy.io import FortranFile, FortranEOFError, FortranFormattingError.

    f = FortranFile(fname, "r")
    recl = ["a8", "i4", "a6", "a1", "i4", "i4", "a1", "i4"] #RECL = integer-value must be present for DIRECT files. 
                                                            #It is the length in bytes of each record in the file. 
    while True :                                            # unknown length of the recl due to varying electron configuration
        try:                                                # it is added up until record can be read
            record = f.read_record(*recl)
            break        
        except ValueError:
            recl += "i4", "i4"
        except FortranEOFError:
            break
        except FortranFormattingError:
            break
    dim = f.read_ints("i4") #nrow, ncol, nzc1  
    matrix = f.read_record("f8").reshape((dim[2],dim[0],dim[1])) #reshape((nzc1,nrows,ncols))

    return record, matrix
```

However, from the second run of the loop, the `f.read_record(*recl)` command is no longer executed, but the **ValueError** is returned directly and the `recl` is extended in the except statement so that the loop runs indefinitely.

If you hit the appropriate `recl` right at the beginning, the file is read. So I think the Fortran code used to create the file is irrelevant, but I can provide it if you like.

I look forward to your comments and advice.

For those of us with an affinity for chemistry: The first record describes the data set with a correction factor for the picture change error and looks like this: 'DFT/PBE ',[6],'cc-pVDZ ','point ','C',[4],[0], 'O',[1],[0],[2].

The entry of the unknown length is the electron configuration with which the calculation was done and is structured like this: "C" : closed shell i,j : i/j electrons in symmetrical / asymmetrical orbital, "O" : open shell n : 0 for no electrons, n >=1 for n * ("i4", "i4") in open shells.

Answer (score 0):

The first attempt to read a record advances the file pointer even if the attempt fails.  You'll have to reset the file pointer if you are going to try again.  Try something like this:

```
    while True :
        try:
            record = f.read_record(*recl)
            break        
        except ValueError:
            recl += "i4", "i4"
            f._fp.seek(0)  # Reset the file pointer to the beginning of the file.
        except FortranEOFError:
            break
        except FortranFormattingError:
            break
```

Note that the leading underscore of the attribute `_fp` indicates that it is intended to be a private attribute.  There is no guarantee that this attribute won't change in future versions of SciPy, so use at your own risk.

Alternatively, you could close and reopen the file:

```
    while True :                                            # unknown length of the recl due to varying electron configuration
        try:                                                # it is added up until record can be read
            record = f.read_record(*recl)
            break        
        except ValueError:
            recl += "i4", "i4"
            f.close()
            f = FortranFile(fname, "r")
        except FortranEOFError:
            break
        except FortranFormattingError:
            break
```